# Giving priority to a token over another

Tags: java, javac, lexer, javacc

Im trying to understand a bit on LEXERS and im wondering how i can give priority to one token over another.
Ill use a real problem i encountered as reference.

I made two tokens, one which represents TEXT and another for a list.
They both share a character which means a list can be also read as a text.

Is there a way to give some sort of priority to which token i want to have it?

I've looked a lot but i didn't find anything that says much on this topic.
I tried putting the definition of the list above the text one but it didn't seem to change anything.

```
TOKEN: {
    <#DIGIT: ["0"-"9"]>
    <#LETTER: ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z"]>
    <#SYMBOLS: ["@" , "."]>
    <#WORD: (<LETTER>|<DIGIT>|<SYMBOLS>)+>
} 


TOKEN: {
     ...
     <LI:  ((<DIGIT>)+)(".")>
     <TEXT:  <WORD>+ >
     ...
 }
```

If i use enter this as an input for the LEXER,

```
1.this is a list
```

I expect to get back,

```
LI as 1.
TEXT as this is a list
```

but the actual output i get is

```
TEXT is 1.this is a list
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [the JavaCC FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm)?  Question 3.3 explains why you are seeing the behaviour that you see.  It's not clear what behaviour you actually want.  For example, do you want that `TEXT` matches any string that it currently does except for those that start with a prefix that matches `LI`?  Please rewrite the question to explain exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two rules that Javacc uses to decide priority,

> RULE 1: priority by the order it occurs while declaring tokens.
>
> RULE 2: priority based longest match possible.

RULE 2 always takes precedence over RULE 1.  That is, JavaCC always matches the longest matchable prefix of the input; and then, if there more than one token matches the longest match, it uses RULE 1 to determine which token to produce.

In your case, you are expecting RULE 1 to be applied but JavaCC uses the Rule 2, the longest match; hence the result.

Furthermore `TEXT` can't match `this is a list` because it contains space character in between, which is not allowed by the definition of `TEXT`.

Token section is for doing lexical analysis only. So use production rules to do the syntactical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The question is "Is there a way to give some sort of priority to which token i want to have it [match]?"

There are several ways.

---

The first way is this

- List the token rules so that the one with highest priority comes first.

But this only works when both rules match strings of the same length.

In your case, you want "1.this" to be matched as an `<LI>` followed by a `<TEXT>`.  But the text rule will match 6 characters, while the `<LI>` rule will only match 2. So, as explained in the the FAQ and @sarath's answer, the `<TEXT>` rule will win.

---

Second way.

- Use lexical states to disable the rule you don't want to win.

This approach is not appropriate for your problem because you need both rules to be active at the same time.

---

Third way.

- Rewrite the rules so that the lower priority rules can not apply to a longer string when the higher priority rule applies.

In your case you want  "1234.this" to not be matched as a `<TEXT>` so that the `<LI>` rule can apply. We will rewrite the `<TEXT>` rule so that it does not apply to any of these strings

```
"1234.this"
"1234.thi"
"1234.th"
"1234.t"
"1234."
```

(Actually, we could allow the last string, and then order the rules so that `<LI>` comes first.  But I found it easier to exclude the last string as well.)

The new token will be called `<TEXT1>` to avoid confusion.  So our rule for `<TEXT1>` will match any string that

- matches `<TEXT>` and that
- does not match `<LI>` and that
- does not have a prefix that matches `<LI>`.

It would be ever so nice if JavaCC provided a nice syntax for this sort of situation, but it doesn't.  We must find a regular expression.

The way that I like to derive regular expressions in cases like this is to start with a regular expression finite state recognizer (REFR) and then derive the regular expression from that.  The definition of REFRs is in slide set 1.2 [here](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Courses/acce/notes.html), as is the algorithm for turning an REFR into a regular expression.

The first REFR for `TEXT1` is as follows.

```
    0s ---P|S|L---> 1f
    0s ---D-------> 2f
    1f --P|S|L|D--> 1f
    2f --D--------> 2f
    2f --S|L------> 1f
```

L means letter, D means digit. P means period. S means any symbol other than period, i.e. the "at" sign.  There are 3 states: 0s, 1f, and 2f. Final (i.e. accepting) states have an "f" in their name.  The start state has an "s" in its name.

Hopefully the correctness of the machine is evident.
In particular, note that, after an input of D or DD or DDD etc., the set of states the machine can be in is {2f}; and, if the machine is in state 2f and a P is the next character, the machine has no state to go to and so the string is rejected.  Thus any string that matches `LI` or has a prefix that matches `LI` will be rejected.

The first step is reduce the number of accepting states to 1 and ensure that there are no outgoing transitions from the accepting state.  (We also want to ensure that there are no incoming transitions to the start state, but this is already the case.) The new machine is

```
    0s ---P|S|L---> 1
    0s ---D-------> 2
    1  --P|S|L|D--> 1
    1  --epsilon--> 3f
    2  --D--------> 2
    2  --S|L-----> 1
    2  --epsilon--> 3f
```

Next eliminate state 2.

```
    0s ---P|S|L----> 1
    0s --D+(S|L)---> 1
    0s ---D+-------> 3f
    1  --P|S|L|D---> 1
    1  --epsilon---> 3f
```

Combine the two transitions from 0s to 1

```
    0s ---P|S|L|D+(S|L)----> 1
    0s ---D+---------------> 3f
    1  ---P|S|L|D----------> 1
    1  ---epsilon----------> 3f
```

Eliminate state 1.

```
    0s ---(P|S|L|D+(S|L)) (P|S|L|D)*---> 3f
    0s ---D+---------------------------> 3f
```

Combine the transitions to get

```
     (P|S|L|D+(S|L)) (P|S|L|D)*  | D+
0s--------------------------------------> 3f
```

Finally, we take a look at the RE to see that it actually makes sense and to look for any simplifications.

To me it seems right and I can't see any way to simplify it.

And we are done.